# Visualising relationships in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5

I have two polygon feature classes related through a key field. I can see the relationship through the attribute table but I'd like to visualise the relationship.

The ideal process would be if click on a polygon, I could run a tool that would highlight all other polygons related. I can workout that way to set it up though.

I'm using ArcMap 10.5.

Comment: Have you investigated using relationship classes?

Comment: I'd use page definition query, and select relevant page/polygon instead of click.

Comment: i think scripting for definition query will much be easier. You can go ahead to get the spatial extent of the related polygons.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes - but these do not visualise the relationship but instead shows the relationship through a table. The process would be that I would click polygon A and polygons B and C (that are related) would highlight.